# How to check if a Row is already in a DataTable?

Tags: c#, datatable

I created a `DataTable` as follows

```
        DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();            
        DataColumn dc = new DataColumn();

        dc.ColumnName = "Table Allocated";
        dt2.Columns.Add(dc);

        dc = new DataColumn();
        dc.ColumnName = "Capacity";
        dt2.Columns.Add(dc);
```

Added some Rows to it, 
Later Created another row like this

```
            DataRow resRow;
            resRow = dt2.NewRow();

            resRow["Table Allocated"] = "1"
            resRow["Capacity"] = "xx";
```

How can i check if resRow is already present in the `DataTable` dt2 aginist all columns in the best way?

Comment: How about iterate in your datatable rows and check it's cells match with your `resRow` cells? That doesn't sound a hard problem. Have you tried anything?

Comment: A datarow is present or not present. Not half or 'the best way'

Comment: @Soner Gönül i tried that , i was thinking if their was any other methods to do that ...

Answer (score 1):

you can try this

```
    var results = from myRow in dt2.AsEnumerable()
    where myRow.Field<string>("Table Allocated") == resRow["TableAllocated"] 
    && myRow.Field<string>("Capacity")==resRow["Capacity"] 
    select myRow;
```

if result.count()>0 then there is a row.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
var rowPresent = dt2.Select("Table Allocated=" + resRow["TableAllocated"] + " AND Capacity = '" + resRow["Capacity"] + "'");
```

Now you can check if `rowPresent` contains any values and -if not- add the new row to the `DataTable`

Answer (score 0):

One solution can be to use RowFilter:

```
var dataView = new DataView(dt2);
dataView.RowFilter = string.Format("TableAllocated='{0}', tableAllocatedValue);
```

Another solution is to use Select

```
dt.Select(string.Format("TableAllocated='{0}', tableAllocatedValue));
```